# Unknown provider: ngAriaProvider <- ngAria

Tags: angularjs

Unknown provider: ngAriaProvider <- ngAria

I am trying to use parts of this demo. I am getting an error with provider.

http://simpulton.github.io/angularjs-mailchimp-signup/

source

https://github.com/simpulton/angularjs-mailchimp-signup

bower.json

```
        {
          "name": "test",
          "version": "0.0.0",
          "dependencies": {
            "angular": "^1.4.7",
            "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
            "angular-animate": "^1.4.7",
            "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
            "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
            "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
            "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
            "angular-touch": "^1.3.0",
            "angular-stripe": "~4.2.8",
            "angular-payments": "*",
            "angular-aria": "^1.4.8",
            "angular-messages": "^1.4.8"
          },
          "devDependencies": {
            "angular-mocks": "^1.3.0"
          },
          "appPath": "app",
          "moduleName": "testApp",
          "overrides": {
            "bootstrap": {
              "main": [
                "less/bootstrap.less",
                "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
                "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

Controller

```
            var testApp = angular.module('testApp');

            testApp.controller('SignUpController', ['$scope','$location', '$resource','$modal', '$cookieStore' , '$http', 'ngAria', 'ngMessages', 'ngAnimate', function ($scope, $location, $resource, $modal, $cookieStore, $http, ngAria, ngMessages, ngAnimate) {

              var ctrl = this, newCustomer = { email:'', userName:'', password:'' };

              var signup = function () {
                if( ctrl.signupForm.$valid) {
                  ctrl.showSubmittedPrompt = true;
                  clearForm();
                }
              };

              var clearForm = function () {
                ctrl.newCustomer = { email:'', userName:'', password:'' }
                ctrl.signupForm.$setUntouched();
                ctrl.signupForm.$setPristine();
              };

              var getPasswordType = function () {
                return ctrl.signupForm.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password';
              };

              var toggleEmailPrompt = function (value) {
                ctrl.showEmailPrompt = value;
              };

              var toggleUsernamePrompt = function (value) {
                ctrl.showUsernamePrompt = value;
              };

              var hasErrorClass = function (field) {
                return ctrl.signupForm[field].$touched && ctrl.signupForm[field].$invalid;
              };

              var showMessages = function (field) {
                return ctrl.signupForm[field].$touched || ctrl.signupForm.$submitted
              };


              ctrl.showEmailPrompt = false;
              ctrl.showUsernamePrompt = false;
              ctrl.showSubmittedPrompt = false;
              ctrl.toggleEmailPrompt = toggleEmailPrompt;
              ctrl.toggleUsernamePrompt = toggleUsernamePrompt;
              ctrl.getPasswordType = getPasswordType;
              ctrl.hasErrorClass = hasErrorClass;
              ctrl.showMessages = showMessages;
              ctrl.newCustomer = newCustomer;
              ctrl.signup = signup;
              ctrl.clearForm = clearForm;

              }])
              .directive('validatePasswordCharacters', function () {
                return {
                  require: 'ngModel',
                  link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                    ngModel.$validators.lowerCase = function (value) {
                      var pattern = /[a-z]+/;
                      return (typeof value !== 'undefined') && pattern.test(value);
                    };
                    ngModel.$validators.upperCase = function (value) {
                      var pattern = /[A-Z]+/;
                      return (typeof value !== 'undefined') && pattern.test(value);
                    };
                    ngModel.$validators.number = function (value) {
                      var pattern = /\d+/;
                      return (typeof value !== 'undefined') && pattern.test(value);
                    };
                    ngModel.$validators.specialCharacter = function (value) {
                      var pattern = /\W+/;
                      return (typeof value !== 'undefined') && pattern.test(value);
                    };
                    ngModel.$validators.eightCharacters = function (value) {
                      return (typeof value !== 'undefined') && value.length >= 8;
                    };
                  }
                }
              })
            ;
```

Error:

```
            Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngAriaProvider <- ngAria <- SignUpController
            http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=ngAriaProvider%20%3C-%20ngAria%20%3C-%20SignUpController
                at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
                at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4334:19
                at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4482:39)
                at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4339:45
                at getService (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4482:39)
                at invoke (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4514:13)
                at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4531:27)
                at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9197:28
                at link (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:977:26)
                at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8841:9) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">
```

route:

```
  .when('/SignUp', {
    templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
    controller: 'SignUpController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
  })
```

signup.html

```
            <div class="signup-wrapper">
              <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/signup/logo.png" alt="Logo"/>
              </div>
              <div class="alert alert-success message-animation" role="alert" ng-if="ctrl.showSubmittedPrompt">
                Thank you! Your account has been created.
              </div>
              <form name="ctrl.signupForm" ng-submit="ctrl.signup()" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':ctrl.hasErrorClass('email')}">
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" type="email" required
                         ng-model="ctrl.newCustomer.email" ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'default blur' }"
                         ng-focus="ctrl.toggleEmailPrompt(true)" ng-blur="ctrl.toggleEmailPrompt(false)"/>


                  <div class="my-messages">
                    <div class="prompt message-animation" ng-if="ctrl.showEmailPrompt">
                      What's your email address?
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="my-messages" ng-messages="ctrl.signupForm.email.$error" ng-if="ctrl.showMessages('email')">
                    <div class="message-animation" ng-message="required">
                      <strong>This field is required.</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="message-animation" ng-message="email">
                      <strong>Please format your email correctly.</strong>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':ctrl.hasErrorClass('userName')}">
                  <label for="userName">Username</label>
                  <input id="userName" name="userName" class="form-control" type="text" required
                         ng-model="ctrl.newCustomer.userName" ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'default blur' }"
                         ng-focus="ctrl.toggleUsernamePrompt(true)" ng-blur="ctrl.toggleUsernamePrompt(false)"/>

                  <div class="my-messages">
                    <div class="prompt message-animation" ng-if="ctrl.showUsernamePrompt">
                      Choose a username that contains only letters and numbers, or use your email address.
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="my-messages" ng-messages="ctrl.signupForm.userName.$error" ng-if="ctrl.showMessages('userName')">
                    <div class="message-animation" ng-message="required">
                      <strong>This field is required.</strong>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>

                  <div class="input-group" ng-class="{'has-error':ctrl.hasErrorClass('password')}">
                    <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" required
                           type="{{ctrl.getPasswordType()}}"
                           ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'default blur' }"
                           ng-model="ctrl.newCustomer.password"
                           validate-password-characters/>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.signupForm.showPassword"> Show
                                    </span>
                  </div>

                  <div class="my-messages" ng-messages="ctrl.signupForm.password.$error" ng-if="ctrl.showMessages('password')">
                    <div class="message-animation" ng-message="required">
                      <strong>This field is required.</strong>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="password-requirements" ng-if="!ctrl.signupForm.password.$valid">
                    <ul class="float-left">
                      <li ng-class="{'completed':!ctrl.signupForm.password.$error.lowerCase}">One lowercase character</li>
                      <li ng-class="{'completed':!ctrl.signupForm.password.$error.upperCase}">One uppercase character</li>
                      <li ng-class="{'completed':!ctrl.signupForm.password.$error.number}">One number</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="selfclear clearfix">
                      <li ng-class="{'completed':!ctrl.signupForm.password.$error.specialCharacter}">One special character</li>
                      <li ng-class="{'completed':!ctrl.signupForm.password.$error.eightCharacters}">Eight characters minimum</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                  <div class="alert alert-success message-animation" role="alert" ng-if="ctrl.signupForm.password.$valid">
                    Your password is secure and you are good to go!
                  </div>
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Create My Account</button>
              </form>
            </div>
```

App.js

```
            angular.module('testApp', [
                'angularPayments',
                'ngAnimate',
                'ngCookies',
                'ngResource',
                'ngRoute',
                'ngSanitize',
                'ngTouch',
                'mm.foundation',
                'angularSpinner',
                'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect',
                'ngMessages',
                'ngAria'
              ])
              .config(function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                  .when('/', {
```

index.html

```
        <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
        <!-- bower:js -->
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-stripe/release/angular-stripe.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-payments/lib/angular-payments.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
        <!-- endbower -->
        <!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: Are you seeing any other errors? What about in the network tab, do you see any files that are 404'ing?

Comment: just a 404 on a font. No other errors. glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
/app/fonts
404
Not Found
font (index):265
Parser

Comment: Could there be a version issue with aria.js ?

Comment: After a little research, I see the problem. I updated/undeleted my previous answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngAria` doesn't need to be injected into the controller. It has a provider that you can manage when you're bootstrapping (by injecting `$ariaProvider`), and that's it. According to documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/accessibility

You should remove that dependency from your controller and it will work fine.

In fact, is that the entire controller? You are injecting a lot of unused dependencies. The example source you referenced doesn't have any of them either, now that I just looked at it.

Comment: That was in my project. See updated question. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Phil Well `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngAriaProvider <- ngAria` means it's not loaded. So if you are listing it as a dependency in your app, then are you sure you've included the `ng-aria` file?

Comment: Please see updated questions. I posted full controller.

Comment: I'm not talking about the controller. I'm talking about at the top (or bottom) of your `index.html` where you are adding all of the external scripts. Are you sure you didn't forget the `ng-aria` file? This problem is not in your markup or controller file. It simply can't find the `ngAria` module.

Comment: We can move comments to the main thread and I will delete this answer for now, since you updated your question, this answer is no longer relevant.

Comment: Please see the index html with bower components in updated question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - Antiga. Works great.